# how to pass arguments into xargs EOF

Tags: bash, xargs

I try to use following command to sent out 4 spark jobs in parallel, and wait for all of them finished before starting new step. However I notice the `$cmd_trainSparkModelx` commands are empty inside 'xargs'. How to pass them into `xargs`?

```
eval $cmd_prepare_step

xargs -P 4 -I {} sh -c 'eval "$1"' - {} <<'EOF'
#eval "$cmd_trainSparkModel1"
#eval "$cmd_trainSparkModel2"
#eval "$cmd_trainSparkModel3"
#eval "$cmd_trainSparkModel4"
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel1"
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel2"
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel3"
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel4"
EOF

echo "finished training"
eval $cmd_postTraining_step
```

Comment: If you want the here-text evaluated, don't quote the `EOF` at the start of the here document.

Comment: @EricBackus works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

following command works. But would still like to see how to make xargs work, as it can also control how many jobs to run at the same time.

```
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel1" &
p1=&!
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel2" &
p2=&!
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel3" &
p3=&!
echo "$cmd_trainSparkModel4" &
p4=&!
wait $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4
```